# How to fill data upto a size in multiple disk?

Tags: powershell, storage

I am creating 4 mountpoint disk in Windows OS. I need to copy files up to a threshold value (say 50 GB).

I tried with vdbench. It works fine, but it throws an exception at last.

```
compratio=4
dedupratio=1
dedupunit=256k

* Host Definition section

hd=default,user=Administator,shell=vdbench,jvms=1
hd=localhost,system=localhost

********************************************************************************
* Storage Definition section


fsd=fsd1,anchor=C:\UnMapTest-Volume1\disk1\,depth=1,width=1,files=1,size=5g
fsd=fsd2,anchor=C:\UnMapTest-Volume2\disk2\,depth=1,width=1,files=1,size=5g
fwd=fwd1,fsd=fsd*,operation=write,xfersize=1m,fileio=sequential,fileselect=random,threads=10
rd=rd1,fwd=fwd1,fwdrate=max,format=yes,elapsed=1h,interval=1
```

Below is the exception from vdbench. Due to this my calling script would fail.

```
05:29:14.287 Message from slave localhost-0:
05:29:14.289 file=C:\UnMapTest-Volume1\disk1\\vdb.1_1.dir\vdb_f0001.file,busy=true
05:29:14.290 Thread: FwgThread write C:\UnMapTest-Volume1\disk1\ rd=rd1 For loops: None
05:29:14.291
05:29:14.292 last_ok_request: Thu Dec 28 05:28:57 PST 2017
05:29:14.292 Duration: 16.92 seconds
05:29:14.293 consecutive_blocks: 10001
05:29:14.294 last_block:         FILE_BUSY           File busy
05:29:14.294 operation:          write
05:29:14.295
05:29:14.296 Do you maybe have more threads running than that you have
05:29:14.296 files and therefore some threads ultimately give up after 10000 tries?
05:29:14.300 *
05:29:14.301 ******************************************************
05:29:14.302 * Slave localhost-0 aborting: Too many thread blocks *
05:29:14.302 ******************************************************
05:29:14.303 *
05:29:21.235
05:29:21.235 Slave localhost-0 prematurely terminated.
05:29:21.235
05:29:21.235 Slave aborted. Abort message received:
05:29:21.235 Too many thread blocks
05:29:21.235
05:29:21.235 Look at file localhost-0.stdout.html for more information.
05:29:21.735
05:29:21.735 Slave localhost-0 prematurely terminated.
05:29:21.735
java.lang.RuntimeException: Slave localhost-0 prematurely terminated.
        at Vdb.common.failure(common.java:335)
        at Vdb.SlaveStarter.startSlave(SlaveStarter.java:198)
        at Vdb.SlaveStarter.run(SlaveStarter.java:47)
```

I am using PowerShell in a Windows machine. Even if some other tools like Diskspd is having way to fill data up to some threshold then please provide me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Work around thin-provisioned SAN storage or virtual disk?

Comment: @vonPryz I have updated the question. I need to copy multiple volumes in parallel upto some mentioned size

Comment: Why would you [like to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? If this is really about thin-provisioning or, say, contest for shared IO resource, parallel copy does not make things faster.

Comment: @vonPryz Yes ,it is to check thin provisioning . Parallel makes no difference??Thanks .. then i think it is Ok to have sequential. But Vdbnech throws error after execution instead of success. so my script which executes it will fail. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: "Do you maybe have more threads running than that you have files and therefore some threads ultimately give up after 10000 tries?" - I'm not at all familiar with `vdbench` but in the storage section definition you have `files=1` and `threads=10` - might this not be the issue?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you . Your comment helped me. Vdbench works now. Files and threads should be same it seems. you can answer it , i would select as answer as it is

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.

I have done this using Diskspd.exe as below

The following command fill 50 GB data in the mentioned disk folder

```
.\diskspd.exe -c50G -b4K -t2 C:\UnMapTest-Volume1\disk1\testfile1.dat
```

It is very simple than Vdbench for my requirement.

> Caution : But it is not having real data so array side disk size is
>   not shown up with the size